# Is there a bzrlib function that will return all of the dotted revnos if given a start and end revision number?

Tags: python, bazaar

I would like to somehow return every single revno and dotted revno between two revision numbers.

If I made the input `1010..1000` how could I get all of the revision numbers inbetween back?

If there  was  a branch off of rev number 1005 and each of those dotted revnos were

`997.5.1 - 997.5.3`

How could I return:

```
list = [1010, 1009, 1008, 1007, 1006, 1005, 997.5.3, 997.5.2, 997.5.1, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Branch.iter_merge_sorted_revisions` to iterate through the revisions in a range. It takes a start and stop revision_id as arguments.

You can use `Branch.dotted_revno_to_revision_id` to convert dotted revnos to revision ids.

Comment: I figured out your exact answer this morning. I was coming on here to answer myself. However, I believe the method is actually `iter_merge_sorted_revisions`